# Set ng-style/style attribute on an li-tag with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

That code is working:

```
<ul>
  <li style="width:100%;"  ng-repeat="period in row.entity.dayViewModels[row.grid.columns.indexOf(col)].periods" >
    <a style="background: rgb({{::period.color}})">{{::period.title}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I want is to format the li-tag with the background color from period.color NOT the a-tag.

But setting ng-style/style on the li-tag did not work because then the period is unknown...

How can I format the li-tag then?

Comment: How you tried to put ng-style in li element? your ```period``` is available in <li> element, so <li ng-style="background: rgb(period.color)""> should work

Comment: Works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/KHkvq0ETAEhinbff9psq?p=preview. Where is the code that **doesn't** work, so that we can find where the problem is?

Comment: @JBNizet odd, it appears the plunker you posted works fine in Chrome but not in IE.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I do agree though, `ng-repeat` is the right solution

Comment: @Pascal Can you try to use ng-attr-style instead?

Comment: style works, I forgot the rgb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... I think period is known on li tag.
I wrote simple example that implement what you want: http://jsbin.com/dosohehopa/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: When I use it in my production environment the ng-style with period does not work on the li-tag. No background is rendered...

Comment: WORKS NOT on li-tag =>  ng-style="{'background': rgb( {{::period.color}}) }" WORKS on li-tag => style="background: rgb( {{::period.color}})" Why does ng-style not work?

Comment: And the style that works does only in Chrome LOL in IE 11 and FF latest on windows 8.1 there are no background colors.

Comment: Try to write ng-style like this (period.color contains string like "255, 200, 40"):
ng-style="{'background': 'rgb(' + period.color + ')'}"

Comment: Your code worked fine on Chrome/IE/FF Thanks but how do you make ng-Style work together with one-time binding => {{::Property}}   ???

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-style="{backgroundColor: period.color}"  ng-repeat="period in row.entity.dayViewModels[row.grid.columns.indexOf(col)].periods" >
    <a>{{::period.title}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For the IE11 issue.. use ng-attr-style attribute instead of style.
Eager processing of the style attribute treated {{::item.color }} as bgcolor value which is invalid. Hence the colors are not refleted.

Comment: Where is ng-attr-style documented? I can not find any source about it?